# Angular doesn't restore null-but-valid input value on model change when input is invalid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have run across a weird/confusing behavior with `<input>` and form validation.

Essentially, if input has an invalid numeric value (which sets `form.$valid` to `false`), if a model value is changed to `null`, it sets the `$valid` flag back to `true`, but doesn't change the value displayed in the input field.

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ssHzQXRU7c6zEY5B7BPW?p=preview) to illustrate. Follow these steps to reproduce:

1. Modify value of a cell to empty.
2. Click on *save* link (which saves `null` into model)
3. Input a non-numeric character.
4. Click on *reset* link (which restores `null` from model)
5. Observe that the input field is no longer invalid, but the invalid character is still there.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm starting to believe that it is a bug. I "fixed" it by introducing another directive that forces `""` value for `null`.
Here's a [fork of the plunker above](http://plnkr.co/edit/biHECYl6tshbN7NGrazs?p=preview) with the "fix".

**EDIT2:**

This was fixed in v1.3+

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine but you forgot to add a validation check at app.js

```
 this.save = function(){
      if($scope.mainForm.$valid && !this.get() == ""){
          old_num = num;
      }
 };
```

You should only save the value when the form is valid.

However that is not a full prove solution as the entire form has to be valid in order for save to work. To further improve the algorithm, i suggest that you mark the validity of individual model and you check validity to the individual model.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't help me. The issue happens what I save a valid (e.g. empty/null) value, but can't restore it. So, using your suggestion doesn't fix the bug I described.

Comment: Again, my issue is with a very specific form validation behavior. It has little bearing on how/when I save the form.

Comment: You can't check for empty values first? Check for my modification. I have added a check to see if the value is empty or not. I tested and it works in my side. All the best

Comment: Unless you are saying that a valid input is valid?

Comment: I don't have a problem with saving - I have a problem with resetting. I don't understand what your fix is fixing. Have you followed the repro steps in the question?

Comment: All i can tell you is the saving process has some error. It shows undefined in the log. I have followed you steps FYI! And please do a console.log at the reset and you will see an undefined error occuring.

Comment: it's not an error - it's a log message that I put there to see what's going on. When a value is invalid, `ngModel` directive sets the model to `undefined`. The problem is when I'm trying to set the model back to `null` - invalid flag is reset, but the invalid value stays in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, I solved it by first doing:

`form.$rollbackViewValue()` or `form.field.$rollbackViewValue` if it was `.$invalid` before doing any of my other reset code.

In your example, you could change to something like:

`<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="cellForm.$rollbackViewValue(); item[prop].reset()">reset</button>`

Comment: This was, in fact, a bug - it was fixed in v1.3+